# Conceptual matrix question

Tags: matrices

Suppose we have matrices $A$ and $B$. We only know that 
$AB=0$ .
Can we just say from this that either matrix $A$ or matrix $B$ is a null matrix?
Or is it possible that neither $A$ nor $B$ is a null matrix,but their product is?

Comment: Try for example $\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&0\end{bmatrix}$ and $\begin{bmatrix}0&0\\0&1\end{bmatrix}$.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to have $AB=0$ with neither $A$ nor $B$ being the zero matrix. One example is
$$ A=\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&0\end{bmatrix}$$
and
$$ B=\begin{bmatrix}0&0\\0&1\end{bmatrix}$$

However, if $AB=0$ and $A$ is invertible, then $B=0$, and similarly if $AB=0$ and $B$ is invertible.

Answer (score 0):

I will give a conceptual answer to this conceptual question. Matrices correspond to linear transformations. It is certainly possible for the composition of two linear transformations to be $0$ even if neither one is. For example, if one transformation $T$ sends everything except a one dimensional linear subspace $U$ to $0$, and the other transformation $T'$ sends everything except a one dimensional linear subspace to $0$, which it sends to a one dimensional linear space other than $U$, then the composition $T\circ T'$ is of course $0$.

Answer (score 0):

Another fancier way of asking the same question is "Does the set of all matrices have any zero divisors under multiplication?" Zero divisors being two elements you can combine to make 0.

Remember this property:
$$det(AB) = det(A)det(B)$$

Since the determinant of the zero matrix is zero, it is possible to make the zero matrix using singular (non-invertable) matrices. But, if we only use invertable matrices, then we can never make zero.